# How to set custom EmptyView for listview in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I want to show a custom view as empty view in my list view in Drawer Layout!
I create a view in xml like this and called it view_custom_empty.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFff0000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="NO RESULT"
        android:textColor="#FFffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in my activity i set list view emptyview like this:

```
View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_custom_empty, null);
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) drawerLayout.getParent();
viewGroup.addView(emptyView, 0);

drawerListview.setEmptyView(emptyView);
drawerListview.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
```

But my custom empty view does not appear in my listview when it's empty!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem and finally found a solution to it.
You could actually set a separate `layout.xml` as an empty view, but then it won't be in the drawer, but inside the activity itself.

### The `activity_main.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- Your activity content here-->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    <!-- Your ListView you want to be shown if not empty-->
        <ListView
          android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>

  <!-- Here starts the empty view Layout-->
          <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFff0000"
            android:visibility="gone">

          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="NO RESULT"
            android:textColor="#FFffffff" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### Add the `empty_view` to your list like this:

```
drawerListview.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
drawerListview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
```

---

Step by step on how to add an EmptyView to your list in the Navigation Drawer

1. Add your EmptyView (Layout) as a child of `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` inside the layout of your Navigation Drawer.
2. Set the Layouts/ Views visibility which holds the EmptyView to gone. In your case RealtiveLayout `android:visibility="gone"`
3. Add a Id to the Layout/View from point 2, you refer to in the activity
4. Add the EmptyView to your list like this: `drawerListview.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
   drawerListview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view));`

---

### **Explanation:**

The whole Navigation drawer actually works without `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`. But adding your list and the empty view as a child, makes sure the child items are inside the navigation drawer and not inside your content area. It also sets the Navigation drawer width automatically to match the Material design guidelines on all screen sizes.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you set your adapter to something not null, the empty view will be dismissed. You need to setAdapter when it's ready to be shown.